# So, you want a pancake for a planet?

Tags: space, earth-like

You know, flat earthers, who think the planet is flat. Well lets say they are completely right that that the planet is flat. That all the videos and pictures and stuff is fake or is an effect of the flat earth void or something, as the void made out of handwavium. Almost everything we know has been wrong, what is the effect on space travel? Etc: Will humans just forget about it, or will we try and explore this void of handwavium?

Comment: What space travel? Didn't you just say that the world is flat and all those fancy so-called spacecraft are illusions planted by the devil? The world is flat, man, and the stars are nothing but pinholes in the firmament through which shines the light of paradise or hell.

Comment: Welcome to WB!  I strongly suggest that you discuss this on [meta] or chat, and I hope that the more experienced members will help adjust this question so it’s not “too broad” (and still has existing answers make sense).  I hope you’ll continue to participate and enjoy WB!

Answer (score 2):

Well space travel could definitely still be possible, however that statement does rest on the premise that you redefine what space is (*because, well.. space as we know it doesn't exist!*).

Since you didn't exactly specify, I'm going to take the approach that the universe generally behaves as the brilliant contributors of the [Flat Earth Wiki](https://wiki.tfes.org/) say it does.

---

**Physics according to Flat-Eathers.**

If you do accept this, then this thing you call the "void" is actually the Aether, a substance that permeates the universe and causes the force known as Universal Acceleration or UA which causes certain celestial bodies (the sun, moon, planets, stars and earth mainly) within the universe to accelerate and move in a direction opposite to that traditionally believed to be maintained by the force of gravity on earth (gravity of course doesn't actually exist however).

For some reason UA does not affect objects created from mass taken from these formally mentioned celectial bodies; this explains why we feel as if we are being pulled down and why things seem to fall back down when they are dropped. In fact, we aren't being pulled and things don't fall at all; the world is just accelerating towards them.

---

**How to travel through "space".**

As space rockets of any description are discrete objects seperated from our planet they are not affected by UA, which by the way accelerates things at a rate of 9.8 meters per second squared.

To be able to move your spacecraft away from the earth in an upwards direction (a direction concordant with the direction it is already travelling in) would simply require a constant acceleration greater then 9.8m/s^2. There are already [proposed methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_travel_using_constant_acceleration) of maintaining such an acceleration to explore the stars, there is no reason why this wouldn't work in our flat earth world (*currently proposed methods are theoretical and whether they are plausible is another question entirely*).

To move your spacecraft in a downwards direction (a direction opposite to the direction it is already travelling in) away from the earth would require nothing at all. Simply turn off your engines and let the Aetheric Winds(UA) do the work for you. Getting back to the earth could take a while however (perhaps even a very, very, very long time...), depending on how long before you turn your "*constant acceleration drive*" back on and how much acceleration it permits...so watch out for that.

Travelling in a direction perpendicular to the direction of the earth could easily be done with normal, traditional rocket engines coupled with a "*constant acceleration drive*" set to match the acceleration of the planet so you don't go flying downwards relative to it.

There you have it. By combining all these methods you can now feasibly travel anywhere you like. Well done!

---

**Would we want to though?**

Well, according to most Flat-Earthers, no. Indeed according to them, the sun, stars and other planets are small, uninhabitable and...spherical (*Oh the horror!*). The Aether contains nothing of interest and there is nothing to be learned by exploring it.
Since we are assuming they are correct, then I have to sadly conclude that while entirely possible space travel would be a waste of time.
As effective space travel would be very expensive to accomplish in this scenario (especially since we've never actually done it before), and there would be virtually nothing to be gained from it, it is highly likely that human beings would abandon the idea to try entirely.